# Why don't work x:Bind on DeviceFamily-Type views?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, uwp

I created `MainPage.xaml` (with `MainPage.xaml.cs`) and `MainPage.DeviceFamily-Desktop.xaml`.

In `MainPage.DeviceFamily-Desktop.xaml` i created `ListView` with `DataTemplate` and `ItemSource` binded to collection in VM.
And if i use `x:Bind` (with `x:DataType`) for binding elements in `DataTemplate` then binding not work and i have not binded content in items in `ListView`.
But if i use `Binding` all work fine.

Example:

```
<ItemsControl
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BooksetsCollectionListViewItemTemlate}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding BookSetsCollection}"/>
```

It don't work, but compiled ok.

```
<DataTemplate
     x:Name="BooksetsCollectionListViewItemTemlate"
     x:DataType="models:BookSet">
       <Image
          Source="{x:Bind PictureBooksetsPage, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

It work

```
<DataTemplate
     x:Name="BooksetsCollectionListViewItemTemlate"
     <Image
          Source="{Binding PictureBooksetsPage/>
```

Comment: Maybe stupid question, but do you have PictureBooksetsPage property defined in your MainPage.xaml code-behind defined and filled with data correctly? Because if there's no compilation error, it looks that your property is bind ok, but is just empty.

Comment: No, BookSetsCollection with PictureBooksetsPage filled in VM. And ItemsControl have 86 items. All 86 items show on page, but if i use x:Bind all 86 items without images.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Could you please share more details like your `VM` and `BookSet` and how you implement the binding? A [mcve] would be better.

Comment: Yesterday did not work, today worked fine. Magic... Thank you.